# Why is $HOME being set incorrectly

Tags: unity, lightdm, 16.10, bashrc, gradle

I'm stuck in a login loop because:

1. My `$HOME` variable is being set incorrectly when I login. I logged into a shell via `ttty1` and `echo $HOME` returned `/usr/local/gradle`
2. `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` isn't being sourced when I log in. I tried setting `env HOME=/home/pyler`, and `set HOME=/home/pyler`, logged out then logged back in only to find that `$HOME` was `/usr/local/gradle - again`

This pops up whenever I login graphically via unity:

[image]

The system then logs me out and I'm back to square one.

When and where exactly is `$HOME` being set to `/usr/local/gradle`?

**update**

Found this line in `.xsession-errors`

```
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/usr/local/gradle
```

Question is how do I stop this.

Comment: Your home directory is normally set in `/etc/passwd` (you can edit it with `sudo vipd`

Comment: That should be `sudo vipw`

Comment: What's the output of `getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d : -f 6` and `grep -Fe HOME= /etc/{environment,profile,bash.bashrc} /home/plyer/.{profile,bashrc,xsession}`?

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I ran getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d : -f 6" and got /home/pyler as output

Comment: @DavidFoerster I ran getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d : -f 6" and got /home/pyler as output. Running the second command produced (1) "/etc/environment:PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle:/Documents/programming/android-studio/bin"  (2) "/home/pyler/.bashrc:export HOME=/home/$USER" (3) "/home/pyler/.bashrc:env HOME=/home/pyler" (4) "grep: /home/pyler/.xsession: No such file or directory."

Comment: @pyler Please edit that into your question. It's difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: @wjandrea I was being courteous to David but none of those results really helped. I had to edit the lightdm.conf file and examine .xsession-errors to really get anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that `lightdm` was not sourcing `/etc/X11/Xsession` so I applied [Paul Hebble's](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/900221) fix.

I also had a hunch that `xorg` or `xauth` were not working properly so I uninstalled them and installed them.

There was no `.xsession` file in `/home/pyler` so I created an empty one and sourced `.bashrc` to ensure that `$HOME` was set to `/home/pyler` before I `reboot` the system.

I ended up logging in without any major problems.

Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the user was not created incorrectly. You can check the `/etc/passwd` file. It will be the second to last column. You can adjust it with this command:

```
usermod -d /home/pyler pyler
```

I'm assuming that the username is pyler based on the information you gave. The first column in `/etc/passwd` will be the exact username.

Comment: I ran that command and I got "usermod: no changes"

Comment: Sorry @pyler that I didn't get back to this in time. Looks like you were able to figure it out though! Nice :)