# Gdm3 not properly setting HOME variable

Tags: home-directory, display-manager

I am stuck in a login loop and I think part of the problem may be that the `HOME` variable is being set to `/usr/local/gradle` which does not exist.

```
lab /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[9145]: 
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/usr/local/gradle
```

This happens every time I restart my system and attempt to login.

What `gdm3` script is doing this? Should I edit it to fix this particular issue?

THanks

Comment: Oddly similar but with `lightdm`: [Why is $HOME being set incorrectly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908891/why-is-home-being-set-incorrectly) - I'm unsure why the accepted answer worked though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried export HOME=/home/levis
But running $ env 
always showed HOME=/usr/local/gradle

So navigated to /etc and ran;
$ sudo grep -rnw $PWD -e gradle

Which produced;
/etc/profile.d/gradle.sh:1:export GRADLE HOME=/usr/local/gradle

I suppose they meant to write GRADLE_HOME

What a typo!