# $HOME incorrectly set to /root for all users (Ubuntu Server 22.04 on Raspberry Pi 3B+)

Tags: server, bash, raspberrypi

The $HOME variable is incorrectly set to "/root" for all users on login on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ board running Ubuntu Server 22.04.

In an SSH session I have to manually `$ export HOME=/home/ubuntu` and `$ source .bashrc` (for the default ubuntu user, it's the same for every user I create).

However this annoyance becomes a problem with VS Code remote for example, as it can't read the profile:

`stderr> -bash: /root/.bash_profile: Permission denied`.

How can I load my user profiles correctly?

---

I've tried running `usermod -d /home/ubuntu ubuntu` as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/908897), but everything is apparently ok (usermod: no changes).

Since I'm running the Pi headless I have no xsession as was OPs problem in the linked thread, so I'm a bit at a loss.

Comment: Should we assume you have checked systemwide login shell initialization files (/etc/profile, /etc/profile.d/*.sh) for offending lines like `HOME=/root`? Does the behavior change if you temporarily set your user's login shell to something different than bash?

Comment: I hadn't, but I have now to no avail. I have grep'ed /home, /etc and /root with `grep -R "\$HOME" .` but not found anything useful. I'm not sure where to look. Changing login shell to /bin/sh have no effect, the output of `cd` is still `-sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /root`

Comment: `file /bin/sh` please.

Comment: `$ file /bin/sh`

`/bin/sh: symbolic link to dash`

Comment: searching in the fog `env` please. Never seen this error.

Comment: It's really strange. I just realised that I can work around it by placing a script in /etc/profile.d with `export HOME=/home/ubuntu`. That seems to work, but I would like to understand why it happened (and if anything else is broken, doesn't seem like it though)

Comment: Output of env, slightly redacted: https://gist.github.com/nicolajknudsen/59980a6fe79829166b5ef669a928ff67

Comment: Maybe stupid question you are not login as root over ssh?

Comment: Not stupid, that would be the obvious, but I'm ssh'ing as the user 'ubuntu', and gets logged in as that user.

Comment: I'm sorry.  What is the system you log over ssh to your raspi?  How did you add new user (which tool/which options)?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem. In my case my /etc/environments file had many entries that were not supposed to be there. After comparing this file with a vanilla system, and removing the extra entries, I got my right vars back.